# Email verification with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, verification

I'm trying to send a verification email when signing up. If the verification works the column "Activated" in a database table will change to "True".
I can send the email successfully but I think there's something wrong with the verification code.
When I press the link sent to the email I get "Forbidden"! I would use some help! Thanks in advance!

```
    app.post('/insertuser', function (_req, res) {
    var data = JSON.parse(_req.body.data);
    var username = data.username;
    var age = data.age;
    var password = data.password;
    var fname = data.fname;
    var lname = data.lname;
    var address = data.address;
    var city = data.city;
    var email = data.email;
    var sq = data.sq;
    var answer = data.answer;
    var pnumber = data.pnumber;
    var dataentered = data.dataentered;
    
    var date = new Date();
    var mail = {
    "id": username,
    "created": date.toString()
    }
    secret_code  = sha1(pnumber) //since pnumber is unique;
    
    const token_mail_verification = jwt.sign(mail, secret_code, { expiresIn: '1d' });
    var url = "http://localhost:3000/verify?username=" + token_mail_verification;

    mysqlConnection.connect(function () {
        var query = "Insert into Customer (Username,Age,Password,First_Name,Last_Name,Email,Address,City,Phone_No,SQ,Answer,Date_Entered) values('" + username + "','" + age + "','" + sha1(password) + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + pnumber + "','" + sq + "','" + answer + "','" + dataentered + "')";
        mysqlConnection.query(query, function (err, results, _fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send('Please try again!');
            }
            else {
                if (results.affectedRows > 0) {
                    var mailOptions = {
                        from: '//myemail',
                        to: email,
                        subject: "Account Verification", 
                        text: "Click on the link below to veriy your account " + url,
                    };
                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            //Handle error here
                            res.send('Please try again!');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                            res.send('Thanks for registering! Please confirm your email! We have sent a link!');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Try again");
                    res.send('Please try again!');
                }

            }
        })
    })
});
```

Verification Code

````
app.get('/verify', function (req, res) {
    token = req.query.id;

    console.log(token)
    if (token) {
        try {
            jwt.verify(token, secret_code, (e, decoded) => {
                if (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    return res.sendStatus(403)
                } else {
                    id = decoded.id;

                    mysqlConnection.connect(function () {
                        var query = " UPDATE  Customers  SET  Activation = 'True' ; WHERE  Email =" + email;
                        mysqlConnection.query(query, function (err, results, _fields) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.send('Please try again!');
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("updated Successfully");
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.sendStatus(403)
        }
    } else {
        return res.sendStatus(403)
    }
});```
````

Comment: This contains a potential SQL injection attack by way of concatenated query strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query parameter is named username not id so the code should like this

```
app.get('/verify', function (req, res) {
    token = req.query.username;
```

Comment: Thanks,  Do you know how to pass value from 
 app.post('/insertuser', function (_req, res) {
  var email = data.email;}

to app.get('/verify', function (req, res){
var email;

Comment: you are welcome, 
why you wanna do that , they are totaly different requests ?!

Comment: In the verify request the query needs the email of the user to update the table

Comment: when you get the coded string back you can decode it and get the username then query your database to get the email, or you can add the email to the coded string

Answer (score -1):

before sending the email you can add the user email to the coded body

```
var mail = {
  username: username,
  email: email,
  created: date.toString()
}
```

and then you can decode it to query the user info or update it,
your else block could look something like this

```
  var email = decoded.email;

  mysqlConnection.connect(function () {
    var query =
      " UPDATE  Customers  SET  Activation = 'True' ; WHERE  Email =" +
      email;
    mysqlConnection.query(query, function (err, results, _fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send("Please try again!");
      } else {
        console.log("updated Successfully");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: This contains a potential SQL injection attack by way of concatenated query strings.